# IE javascript html encoding weirdness

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Put this in your location bar in IE

```
javascript:location.href='http://www.google.com/search?q=something&lt=bar'
```

Watch in horror as it helpfully thinks `&lt` actually means `&lt;` and makes it a `<`.

WTF is going on here?

Other browsers don't do this.
How do I prevent IE from doing this?

Comment: IE should die. Atleast, IE6 should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is part of an HTML document you should escape the & by replacing it by &amp;

An ampersand '&' in HTML mark the start of a character reference entity such as &lt; &gt; and &eacute;

Literal ampersands in your document should be written as &amp;

Note that if that code is generated dynamical you should also escape the URL so that it can appear in a JavaScript string as well.

**Edited:** I can confirm this particular problem occurs when pasting JavaScript code directly in the address bar. It seems HTML character escaping rules are irrelevant here after all.

I've googled a bit and found this [blog post](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200812/accidental_html_entities_in_urls.html) which identify that particular behavior as an ie bug.

Comment: This occurs even when you run javascript in the location bar.
It would even occur when referring the function from a .js file.

And doing this would break every other browser which doesn't expect javascript strings to be encoded. (It breaks chrome and firefox for sure - not sure about Opera)

Comment: @HS Your're right. I found this blog post about the issue it looks like an ie bug http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200812/accidental_html_entities_in_urls.html

Comment: Nice find. I tried googling but didn't know what keywords to use. Re-arranging the query string would solve this problem. Thanks. I'm going to mark this answer as 'correct' - edit your post to add this link to it.